# Error Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS with add domain

Tags: login, connection, domain-server, sssd

We have an issue with Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS.

We are trying to add domain and we can't.

```
Feb 18 09:32:26 nginx sshd[8383]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=::1  user=user17
Feb 18 09:32:26 nginx sshd[8383]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=::1 user=user17
Feb 18 09:32:26 nginx sshd[8383]: pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied for user user17: 4 (System error)
Feb 18 09:32:26 nginx sshd[8383]: Failed password for user17 from ::1 port 55910 ssh2
Feb 18 09:32:26 nginx sshd[8383]: fatal: Access denied for user user17 by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

Comment: the problem was the parameter in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
Change :
UsePAM no
to:
UsePAM yes

systemctl restart sshd.service

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the parameter in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
Change :

```
UsePAM no
```

to:

```
UsePAM yes
```

And

> systemctl restart sshd.service